# What's the best way to remove dead weeds from cracks in concrete?

Tags: concrete, weeds

I just sprayed 'natural' weed killer and now I'm left with dead weeds. How do I go about removing them?

Do I used a gardening knife or something? It's hard to get into the cracks.

[image: weeds in cracks]

Comment: After they're dead (that is an important step), I use a weed eater to remove the dead tops.

Comment: Do you mean just to use a trimmer and get the filament between the cracks?

Comment: I don't even aim for between the cracks, it's spinning so fast it doesn't matter.  Just tilt the string trimmer and do a once over and there gone. My one crack that grows weeds I also hit with Roundup almost every time I mow to get new weeds before they are even visible normally.  I did just have to eliminate them tho since I haven't been mowing yet.

Answer (score 2):

If this was my home, I would do the following to remove the eyesore and minimize the repeat of it happening in the future:

1. Remove what I could with a weed trimmer tipping it to get into the crack as much as possible.
2. Use a power washer or maybe a garden hose with a tight nozzle to clean out the cracks as much as possible.
3. After it has dried out, follow the methods listed in the following web page to open up the cracks some and fill with a concrete crack filler product.

https://www.quikrete.com/athome/video-repairing-sealing-cracks.asp

Answer (score 0):

If one is appropriately careful, a quick method of removal involves fire. The safest tool would be a torch designed for this purpose (use your favorite search engine for "weed removal torch" or "weed killing torch") or a simple handyman style torch. The weed specific torch will have a longer reach, minimizing the need to bend over and perhaps providing that much additional safety. Especially as the weeds are dead, they will burn easily, while live weeds may take a bit more fuel.

It would be a good idea to have an extinguishing method nearby, if you have other materials which might ignite. For outdoor applications such as this, a garden hose with a water supply, perhaps a nozzle attached should give you suitable safety.